# Carve 1.4 CSG - C2375: 'cbrt' : redefinition; different linkage

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, redefinition, math.h, csg

I am trying to compile Carve 1.4 c++ library. but keep getting

```
C2375: 'cbrt' : redefinition; different linkage
```

errors.

When i click on an error it takes me to this line in math.h:

```
_CRTIMP double __cdecl cbrt(_In_ double _X);
```

the only other cbrt function i can find relates to this line in a header file that comes with the library called cbrt.h:

```
inline double cbrt(double x)
```

I'm not sure what to change to get it to work. Any ideas?

I've generated the carve-1.4 vcxproj files using CMAKE 3.0.2 with the VS 12 2013 generator.

I'm using boost 1.56, CMAKE 3.0.2, VS 12 2013, windows 7.

With CMAKE, for Carve 1.4 i have turned off 'build_shared_libs' and i've added 'cmake_static_linker_flags' to be the same as the 'cmake_exe_linker_flags'....

```
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS                /machine:X86 

CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG          /debug /INCREMENTAL

CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL     /INCREMENTAL:NO

CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE        /INCREMENTAL:NO

CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO /debug /INCREMENTAL
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that cbrt [is defined here](https://code.google.com/p/carve/source/browse/include/carve/cbrt.h) as

```
inline double cbrt(double x)
```

and in math.h as

```
_CRTIMP double __cdecl cbrt(_In_ double _X);
```

The definitions must match but unfortunately this is a [still standing issue](https://code.google.com/p/carve/issues/detail?id=77).

As a workaround you could either fix the library yourself or do [as point 1 of this answer describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5776016/1938163).